# Storing Key, Value Pair using java

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

I would like to know the best data structure used in java suitable for the following senario.

1. There is a key and a value.
2. And the key is not duplicated,
3. Each Value should store collection of objects where the values in each object will change frequently.

Thanks.

Comment: HashMap is better...you can add synchroined in your code, if you want it thread safe to HashMap. you can also use ConcurrentHashMap(least preferred) as it is synchronized.

Comment: refer [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Multimap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**HashMap**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) should serve your need.

HashMap allows you to store key value pairs as a collection. HashMap does not allow duplicate keys. You can use different collection to be stored as a value in your HashMap. For example to create a map with keys as a String and value as a list, the define it like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Also there are implementations for such collection called MultiMap i.e map where a key is associated with collection of values. Two popular implemantations of MultiMap are:

- Apacha MultiMap
- Guava MultiMap

Comment: shouldn't it be a comment ??

Comment: No as the user is asking which data structure he can use.

Comment: I tried this but unable to add values to the list. Can you please help me providing sample code of how to approach

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid When the question is "I need something that has keys and values", not much separates a comment and an answer.

Comment: @Awinash You need to create the List if not present in his example. Ex. If you want to insert a key A with value B of type T, you need to do List<T> mappedValue=hashMap.get(A); mappedValue=(mappedValue==null) ? new ArrayList<T>() : mappedValue; mappedValue.add(B); hashMap.put(A,mappedValue);

Answer (score 2):

A type of [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You aren't saying much besides "I need a key-value thingy". If you need to iterate the map by insertion order, there is a LinkedHashMap. If you need to iterate the map by ascending or descending key values, there are [sorted maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html). If the map will be shared by multiple threads a [concurrent map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) will be useful. If there will be billions of items in the list and you don't mind hemorraghing data (say this is a caching algorithm), a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) is for you.

If by "key is not duplicated" you mean it is a violation if a key is inserted if it already exists, you have a few options.

Comment: Oops, had an old version of HashMapSet up. Fixed.