# Permanently storing key-value pairs efficiently

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I'm working on an application which requires read/write access to key-value pairs (strings) currently saved in a CSV file. At the moment I'm creating hash maps from the file and overwriting when adding new entries but this is leading to a plethora of problems down the line. What's the best way to store and update this data?

- Only need to store string pairs
- Relatively few entries (<100)
- Must be able to update data

Comment: suppose this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872760/storing-key-value-pair-using-java) has some information with your issue.

Comment: Sqlite or any in memory / file database? What other requirements do you have?

Comment: Define [permanent](http://www.10000yearclock.net/learnmore.html)?

Comment: [Properties](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)? (or just [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html))

Comment: What does 'must be able to update database' mean? If you've already decided on a database why are you asking the question?

Comment: @EJP That's bad wording on my part - I'm was using database to refer to a generic way of storing data. So far properties looks like a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `java.util.Properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have so few entries, I suggest properties files, which are basicly handled as HashMaps.

An example for loading and saving of properties files can be found here:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Happy Coding!